# find: paths must precede expression: `1'

Tags: makefile, find

I'm trying to run a file call buildAll.sh, which is supposed to generate binary files from benchmarks and put them all into the top directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -d 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd {} && make clean && make && cp main.bin ../{}.bin && make clean" \;
```

However, I get an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `1'
```

I'm not sure what how the command works, and how to fix it.

I ran this on Ubuntu.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is shown when a stray argument is found on the command line, which is `1` in this case, as `-d` (i.e `-depth`) doesn't take an argument. However, it seems that you don't need `find` here at all.

```
for dir in ./*/; do
  make -C "$dir" clean &&
  make -C "$dir" &&
  cp "$dir/main.bin" "$dir.bin" &&
  make -C "$dir" clean
done
```